# Sign a transaction with Metamask which will be submitted later using a custom backend

Tags: web3js, metamask, json-rpc, raw-transaction, sendsignedtransaction

Currently have a custom micro-service that sends & creates transactions depending on the use case which utilizes `eth_sendRawTransaction` meaning I'll need a web wallet to prompt the users to sign a transaction & return the signed transaction object from metamask.

Using Web3js.

Issue is many posts & comments are very dated & metamask doesn't support `eth_sign` anymore looking through the [Metamask JSON-RPC API](https://metamask.github.io/api-playground/api-documentation/#personal_sign) I wasn't able to find something that jumped at me telling me I could use that to sign a transaction other than maybe `personal_sign` or `eth_signTypedData_v4`.

What is the current state of signing transactions with Web Wallets which can then be submitted to in house Node or server? Is it not longer possible to sign a transaction with metamask.

On Cardano this process is rather simple, especially when you don't have any `Datum`.

Answer (score 0):

In current scenario you can just create a wallet instance using web3 or ethers depends upon you . After creating wallet you can create wallet using `signMessage` function.
Hope this helps